# Why use a map in Thread to store ThreadLocal objects?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm reading ThreadLocal's source codes.And I get a question which is unable to understand.That is
why use a map to store ThreadLocal objects?I think use array is more suitable.Because you can define ThreadLocal's hashcode from zero.And you do not need to worry about key's collision.
Any one can help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicate of a closed question asked within the same hour by user name "CoverStack": [*Why use map in ThreadLocal*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65949917/642706)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you are saying.

Internally thread locals work by generating an internal key for each the thread local variable.  In recent implementations (I am looking at Java 11) the keys are generated by a hashing algorithm, and are used in the (custom) map that each thread uses to store the thread-local values.

You are proposing that these maps be replaced by simple arrays of values, and the keys are generated as sequentially increasing integers so that they can be used for subscripting the arrays.  I guess you think it would improve performance and/or reduce memory.

---

The problem is that your idea doesn't scale.

Suppose that an application creates a number of `ThreadLocal` instances.  Now suppose that a thread sets the value of the `i`th `ThreadLocal` for some random `i`.

- In the current implementation, an entry is created in the thread's hash table.  This takes a constant amount of space.
- In your proposed implementation, the thread's array now needs to have *at least* `i` slots, where `i` is the key.  (Java arrays are not sparse!).  If it doesn't exist yet, it must be created with length `i`.  If it does exist, it may need to be reallocated with length `i`.

When the number of `ThreadLocal` instances is large enough, and they are set randomly, and only a few are set for any given thread, then the memory used by your array-based representation will be greater than for the current hash table representation.

Then, consider what happens when a `ThreadLocal` is garbage collected.

- In the current hash table implementation, each map entry is (extends) a `WeakReference` whose `ref` refers to a `ThreadLocal`.  When a given `ThreadLocal` instance is garbage collected, all entries in all threads' maps for that `ThreadLocal` will have their `ref` field nulled.  The map's implementation recognizes any such entries as "stale", and when it encounters a stale entry, it expunges it from the table.
- In your proposed implementation, there is no `WeakReference` to break.  Even if that could be worked around, it is difficult to see how the arrays could be compacted.

---

Now, the Sun / Oracle engineers who worked on the Java implementation are all smart people.  And the particular engineers who implemented and maintained `ThreadLocal` over the years probably looked for ways to optimize it.  And they may well have considered using arrays at some point.  But I imagine that they would have considered all of the pros and cons<sup>1</sup> ... before deciding on the current approach of using a hash table per thread.

It is also worth understanding the background for the current implementation.  There are clues in this (fixed) bug report against the JDK 1.4 codebase: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4414045

<sup>1 - These may well have included other issues than the above ones ...</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I am not good at English,so it may be difficult to understand what I am saying.But thank god,you got me.
Then I will talk about my thought.
First,I think it is possible to reuse array index if use an array instead of a map in thread.When a thread local variable is stale, you can reuse that variable's index to store another new thread local variable.For example,a thread local variable store in table[5],If that variable is stale, you can store another thread local in table[5].

Comment: Secondary,you can store entry in array.Entry is a weak reference,So it will be expunged by gc while it working.
My English is not well.Hope you can understand what I am saying.

Comment: I considered both of those things while writing my answer.  While it *may* be theoretically possible, to do one or both of those things, my feeling is that the performance would be a lot worse.  Either way, the onus is on you to *prove* that your approach 1) will work, and 2) is better.  Prove it by implementing it and making the implementation and benchmarks available for others to look at.

Answer (score 0):

The reasons for storing the threadLocals in a map are not specified by any documentation, for as far as I have found.

I would think the reason to be that you would want to prevent multiple references to the same threadLocal to be stored per thread, which can be done easily with a Map.